# Change the "Ship to a different Address" Checkbox to a String

Tags: jquery, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce

I am currently using **woocommerce** and I would like to know if it is possible to change a **checkbox** to a kind of string (anchor with spam, label,..).

The page I'm trying to modify is the *checkout* page. Bellow the **billing details** the client can click on a checkbox and place a different address. When checked a other field form show bellow the checkbox.

What I want to do is to remove the checkbox and replace it with a string with the same purpose.

Someone have an idea how I could do this?

**Code:**

```
<h2 id="ship-to-different-address">
  <label for="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
  <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1"/>
</h2>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the checkbox and associated label? We may be able to achieve your desired result purely with CSS. Regardless, without the code, we can't really tell you how to go about effectively replacing it.

Comment: I've paste the code.

Comment: Have you considered creating a link with the href value set to "#" and binding your click event and callbacks to that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer up a solution that uses only CSS, and a slight re-ordering of your HTML elements. Run the snippet to see it work.

Essentially what is happening, is the `<label>` is styled like a button, the checkbox is hidden off-screen, and its `:checked` state is used for styling the active state of the label.

```css
/*hide the checkbox*/
.checkbox-button .input-checkbox:not(:checked),
.checkbox-button .input-checkbox:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
/*style the label like a button */
.checkbox-button .input-checkbox + label {
  font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* style the label/button active state*/
/* (only applied when the checkbox is 'checked' */
.checkbox-button .input-checkbox:checked + label {
  background: #656565;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="ship-to-different-address" class="checkbox-button">
    <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1"/>
    <label for="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="checkbox">
      Ship to a different address?
    </label>
</h2>
```